# How to loop over a range in order of declining hexadecimal power

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I have a device that my app scans. A scan is over a consecutive range of hexadecimal values. I currently loop over the ranges as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 0xFF00 - 0x0100; i++) {
    SCAN_ADDRESSES[i] = i + 0x0100;
}
```

Scans take a long time and I've found that to most interesting results are at the even hexadecimal values, so I'd like to scan them first. In my example, the desired set would start with the most significant and round hexadecimal values in the range.

```
{
    0xE000, 0xD000, 0xC000, 0xB000, 0xA000, 0x9000, 0x8000, 0x7000, 0x6000, 0x5000, 0x4000, 0x3000, 0x2000, 0x1000,
    0xFE00, 0xFD00, 0xFC00, 0xFB00, 0xFA00, 0xF900, 0xF800, 0xF700, 0xF600, 0xF500, 0xF400, 0xF300, 0xF200, 0xF100,
    ⋮
    0x010F, 0x010E, 0x010C, 0x010B, 0x010A, 0x0109, 0x0108, 0x0107, 0x0106, 0x0105, 0x0104, 0x0103, 0x0102, 0x0101
}
```

The desired range contains all numbers `n` where `0x0100 <= n < 0xFF00`

I don't care each power is iterated in decrementing or incrementing order, as long as the powers themselves are decrementing order. I don't want any duplicates either.

I expect there is some simple loop that will do this. Otherwise there might even be a recursive function that would do what I want. Thanks in advance for help and suggestions. I use guava if anything in that might help me.

Comment: You can generate these indices with two nested loops, one for the rank, aka "number of zeroes in the least-significant positions", and another for the most-significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reverse hex representation of iterated numbers within the same loop. Not sure if this is what you are looking for, because the order will not be strictly ascending or descending. However the "even" adresses are searched first and there are no duplicates.

```
int reversed = ((i&0x000F)<<12) + ((i&0x00F0)<<4)
                + ((i&0x0F00)>>4) + ((i&0xF000)>>12);
```